# Add Mean Trend Line to geom_line plot + R

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, mean, stat

I need to add an average trend line to a `geom_line` line plot in R. The result should be a dotted line on the same chart that that is the average of the values that make up the other lines, like so:

[image]

Here is my example code to make the chart:

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("Jim","Bob","Sue","Sally","Jim","Bob","Sue","Sally","Jim","Bob","Sue","Sally"),
                       Period = c("P1","P1","P1","P1","P2","P2","P2","P2","P3","P3","P3","P3"),
                       Value = c(150, 200, 325, 120, 760,245,46,244,200, 325, 120, 760)
                       )

p<-ggplot(df, aes(x=Period, y=Value, group=Name)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=Name))

p
```

I tried both solutions offered in a similar question, here - [add one mean trend line for different lines in one plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397959/add-one-mean-trend-line-for-different-lines-in-one-plot)

But neither even result in a trend line. Examples:

```
p + stat_smooth( aes( y = Value, x = Period), inherit.aes = FALSE )
p + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `geom_smooth` with `method = "lm"` if you are looking for a trend line?

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = Period, y = Value, group = Name)) +
  geom_line(aes(color= Name)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = 1), method = "lm", size = 1, se = FALSE, linetype = 2,
              color = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly it! What I was missing was the "group" method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `group = 1` in your `aes` of the `stat_summary` to add a mean line for all data like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
p<-ggplot(df, aes(x=Period, y=Value, group=Name)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=Name))
p + stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="line", lwd = 1, linetype ='longdash', aes(group=1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>